# wrong count in query

Tags: mysql

I have a table whose structure is as follows:

```
id  int
userid  int
status  enum ('pending','approved')
dop     datetime
```

Data is as:

```
id          userid               status             dop
 1            24                 pending            2011-02-14 06:41:32
 2            24                 pending            2011-02-15 23:02:45
```

When I fire the following query:

```
SELECT count( userid )
FROM t1
WHERE STATUS = 'pending'
GROUP BY userid
```

It's giving me count as '2', which is wrong, can anyone tell me what's wrong here? and how to get real count as 1

Comment: Have you tried swapping `SELECT count()` for `SELECT *`? That way, you'll see the result of the query, and you may be able to spot why the count is still 2.

Comment: It is not a wrong result, as far as you have two rows. COUNT() is counting rows

Comment: @ggregoire: Why is this wrong... not Why this is wrong.

Comment: @markus : sorry i don't speak english.

Comment: distinct without with group by as suggested below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group by statement is executed after the count. Use this instead:

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT userid )
FROM t1
WHERE STATUS = 'pending'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to count the number of user with status pending then?

```
SELECT count(userid)
FROM t1
WHERE STATUS = 'pending'
GROUP BY status, userid
```

Comment: it's still didn't get me proper count

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the userid in the select clause :

```
SELECT userid, count( userid )
FROM t1
WHERE STATUS = 'pending'
GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding DISTINCT() on userid?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT userid )
FROM t1
WHERE STATUS = 'pending'
GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 0):

You sould use the COUNT(DISTINCT()) construction, it allow you to count the diferent values not NULL ([docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/group-by-functions.html))

Try this sentence:

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT( userid ) )
FROM t1
WHERE STATUS = 'pending'
GROUP BY userid
```

HTH!