# Iincredibly simple query gets wrong results using Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am on the edge right now. I've been trying to get this very simple query to work for the past 2 hours but it will not

All the query does is select all rows where the price is between a range. The query looks like this:

```
select * from `properties` where `price` >= ? and `price` <= ? limit 16 offset
```

It returns the correct result (2 rows) when ran in phpmyadmin

But when I use ->get() or ->count() on it in Laravel, it returns the complete wrong answers.

Here is my full laravel code

```
    $query = Property::query();

    $price_min = Input::get('price_min');
    $price_max = Input::get('price_max', 1000000);

    $query->where('price', '>=', $price_min);
    $query->where('price', '<=', $price_max);

    \DB::enableQueryLog();
    $properties = $query->paginate(16);

    Helper::pr(['found' => count($properties)]);
    Helper::printLastQuery();
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [found] => 8 <----- THIS SHOULD SAY 2
)
Array
(
    [query] => select * from `properties` where `price` >= ? and `price` <= ? limit 16 offset 0
    [bindings] => Array
        (
            [0] => 475944
            [1] => 909796
        )

    [time] => 3
)
```

Comment: What are the results returned? That might provide a hint...

Comment: When I print all the listings, the 2 that should be are there but the rest are properties where the prices are widely out of the provided price range

Comment: Sorry I'm not used to laravel, can't you get the final executed query?

Comment: The first code box is the final ran query :| that's why I am very confused

Comment: No it is the query before bindings. A real MySQL query does not have ? placeholders

Comment: Yes but PHP does not add the bindings, it sends the query then the bindings seperate. The final query looks like that but with the values replacing the `?`

Comment: Since I do not see anything suspissious, I will only be able to express more when I see the query the mysql server ran... My guess is that at least one of the bindings is wrong. Once we know what's wrong, it will be easier to correct.

Comment: I assume result of `count($properties)` gave you the number of columns in the table, is that correct?

Comment: And have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152182/db-count-returning-different-value-from-countdb-get)

Answer (score 0):

**I figured out why it wasn't working**

I had the datatype field as a `text` in the database so that is why it couldn't compare the numbers.

**In my defence**, I created the table from a script that used an XML feed to generate the appropriate columns