# Mysql count left join group by shows unexpected results

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, left-join

Have 2 tables

```
`main_table`
`id_main`  | `name` 
   1       |  'first one'
```

and `supplemental_table`

```
`id_main`  | `value` 
   1       |  'alias 1'    
   1       |  'aka 5'
```

I want to count rows in `main_table` (but i need to join `supplemental_table`).

```
   SELECT COUNT(`main`.`id_main`) FROM `main_table` `main` 
   LEFT JOIN `supplemental_table` `supplemental` 
   ON `main`.`id_main` = `supplemental`.`id_main` 
   WHERE `main`.`name` = 'first one' 
   GROUP BY `main`.`id_main`;
```

In `main_table` is only one row with `id_main` value 1. I use `GROUP BY`. So expect with `SELECT COUNT` to get result 1. But i get result of number of rows in `supplemental_table`.

Here is what i did http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/259055/10

What is wrong with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix here would be to just count distinct `pk` values from the first table:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT main.pk)
FROM main_table main 
LEFT JOIN supplemental_table supplemental
    ON main.id_main = supplemental.id_main
WHERE
    main.name = 'first one'
GROUP BY
    main.id_main;
```

Here `pk` is the primary column or other unique key on the `main_table` table.  The idea here is that the count isn't affected by the join, because each original record on the `main_table` side of the join would still be counted its original number of times.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this would work. Here tested http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/259055/17 But then `GROUP BY` is not necessary https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309302/2360831

Comment: Check my updated answer.  You should be counting the distinct primary key values.